# dataGrid columnIndex rollOver event

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

how to get dataGrid columnIndex rollOver event in flex3

Answer (score 0):

You can add rollOver event handler to whole DataGrid or to each cell via itemRenderer, and after that check `event.columnIndex` property.

Comment: on rollOver event hadler how will i get columnIndex property.

Comment: because rollOver event is a MouseEvent... DataGridEvent,ListEvent handler has columnIndex property.

Comment: Did you try to instance it? It should work 100% if you'll e.g. extend the DataGrid and place overrided handlers inside of your extended class.

Comment: Actuall i need to enable handCursor in my dataGridColumn(for only first column which has link to open popUp) on rollOverEvent.
Earlier i did using itemRender .but when i use itemRender, dataGrid sort column property is not working for that column.
how can i fix this issue..

Comment: if i get the column index on rollOverEvent ,i can easily fix it.

Comment: about sorting - you may override this function in your extended class. about columnIndex, could you please show me yr code, please?

Comment: <mx:DataGrid width="100%" draggableColumns="false" rollOver="showHandCursor(event);"  rollOut="hideHandCursor(event);">
 <mx:columns>
  <mx:DataGridColumn width="8"
  dataField="XXXX" color="blue" textDecoration="underline" 
  headerText="AAAAA" 
  itemRenderer="components.CustomToolTip"/>
 </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>